# How to set source path dynamically to read files from different folders in flink?

Tags: apache-flink

I want to read files everyday, so the path should be always set for current date. How can I do it in flink?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can either generate the path of the file you expect to exist, and then read it, or set up a streaming job that uses file discovery to ingest files as they become available.

See the docs for the [FileSource](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/api/java/org/apache/flink/connector/file/src/FileSource.html) and [readfile](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/datastream/overview/#data-sources). `readfile` is the legacy connector for ingesting files; `FileSource` was introduced in Flink 1.12.

Answer (score 0):

fileInputFormat.setFilesFilter(filter);

I decided to use this but not sure it is a best practice.